# How to get absolute difference estimate and confidence intervals from log(x+1) variable with emmeans

Tags: r, transform, confidence-interval, emmeans

I have a mixed effect model with a log(x+1) transformed response variable. The output from emmeans with the type as "response" provides the mean and confidence intervals for both groups that I am comparing. However what I want is the mean and CI of the difference between the groups (i.e. the estimate). emmeans only provides the ratio (with type="response") or the log ratio (with type="link") and I am unsure how to change this into absolute values. If you run the model without the log(x+1) transformation then emmeans provides the estimated difference and CI around this difference, not the ratios. How can I also do this when my response variable is log(x+1) transformed?

```
bmnameF.lme2 = lme(log(bm+1)~TorC*name, random=~TorC|site, 
data=matched.cases3F, method='REML')

emmeans(lme, pairwise~TorC, 
type='response')%>%confint(OmeanFHR[[2]])%>%as.data.frame

emmeans.TorC    emmeans.emmean  emmeans.SE  emmeans.df  emmeans.lower.CL    emmeans.upper.CL    contrasts.contrast  contrasts.estimate  contrasts.SE    contrasts.df    contrasts.lower.CL  contrasts.upper.CL 
Managed         376.5484          98.66305     25         219.5120             645.9267            Managed - Open       3.390123          1.068689          217             1.821298         6.310297   
Open            111.0722          43.15374     25         49.8994            247.2381              Managed - Open       3.390123          1.068689          217             1.821298         6.310297
```

Comment: In this case, you have one ratio but many possible differences, which one do you want to report?

Comment: I want to report the mean difference and upper and lower confidence intervals in absolute terms. In this case the values are kg, so instead of reporting the ratio of the difference and its CI I want to report the absolute values. However I am unsure how to get these from the output

Comment: ratio = A/B is fixed in your model. difference = A - B = B*ratio - B = B(1-ratio). Your absolute difference values vary with B (or A) values. Therefore, you may not be able to get a single absolute difference unless you want to fix B (and A).

Comment: If I made the same model, but without the log(x+1) transformation of the response variable, then instead of supplying a ratio, the output provided from the code above gives absolute values of the estimate and its LCL/UCL. Is this not possible with log transformed data or is there another way to get this information. I need to present this data to a group that is interested in what the absolute difference is and will not be able to understand odd's ratios.

Comment: That's right. When you fix the difference as constant in your model without log(x+1), you can report a single absolute difference. About presenting results to others who will not be able to understand odds ratios, I feel it is a topic outside of this place.

Comment: Okay, understood. But if I have the difference calculated as A-B or B*ratio-B or B(1-ratio), how do I calculated the CI interval around this? I am unsure what to multiply the LCL/UCL ratios by

Answer (score 1):

Let me show a different example so the results are reproducible to all viewers:

```
mod = lm(log(breaks+1) ~ wool*tension, data = warpbreaks)
```

As you see, with a log transformation, comparisons/contrasts are expressed as ratios by default. But this can be changed by specifying `transform` instead of `type` in the `emmeans()` call:

```
> emmeans(mod, pairwise ~ tension|wool, transform = "response")
$emmeans
wool = A:
 tension response   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 L           42.3 5.06 48     32.1     52.4
 M           23.6 2.83 48     17.9     29.3
 H           23.7 2.83 48     18.0     29.4

wool = B:
 tension response   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 L           27.7 3.32 48     21.0     34.4
 M           28.4 3.40 48     21.6     35.3
 H           19.3 2.31 48     14.6     23.9

Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
wool = A:
 contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 L - M     18.6253 5.80 48  3.213  0.0065 
 L - H     18.5775 5.80 48  3.204  0.0067 
 M - H     -0.0479 4.01 48 -0.012  0.9999 

wool = B:
 contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 L - M     -0.7180 4.75 48 -0.151  0.9875 
 L - H      8.4247 4.04 48  2.086  0.1035 
 M - H      9.1426 4.11 48  2.224  0.0772 

P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates
```

Or, you can do this later via the `regrid()` function:

```
emm1 = emmeans(mod, ~ tension | wool)
emm2 = regrid(emm1)
emm2          # estimates
pairs(emm2)   # comparisons
```

`regrid()` creates a new `emmGrid` object where everything is already back-transformed, thus side-stepping the behavior that happens with contrasts of log-transformed results. (In the previous illustration, the `transform` argument just calls `regrid` after it constructs the reference grid.)

But there is another subtle thing going on: The transformation is auto-detected as `log`; the `+1` part is ignored. Thus, the back-transformed estimates are all too large by 1. To get this right, you need to use the `make.tran()` function to create this generalization of the log transformation:

```
> emm3 = update(emmeans(mod, ~ tension | wool), tran = make.tran("genlog", 1))
> str(emm3)
'emmGrid' object with variables:
    tension = L, M, H
    wool = A, B
Transformation: “log(mu + 1)” 

> regrid(emm3)
wool = A:
 tension response   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 L           41.3 5.06 48     31.1     51.4
 M           22.6 2.83 48     16.9     28.3
 H           22.7 2.83 48     17.0     28.4

wool = B:
 tension response   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 L           26.7 3.32 48     20.0     33.4
 M           27.4 3.40 48     20.6     34.3
 H           18.3 2.31 48     13.6     22.9

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

The comparisons will come out the same as shown earlier, because offsetting all the means by 1 doesn't affect the pairwise differences.

See `vignette("transformations", "emmeans")` or https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html for more details.